# Blackjack: How to build a function that finds the max value of every hand and returns that value in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've written a Blackjack program that consists of multiple functions. I'm having difficulties writing the code for one particular function, which finds the max value of all hands (as inputted by user) and returns it. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
cards_value = {"A":1, "T":10, "J": 10, "K":10, "Q": 10 }
def get_total(card):
    return cards_value[card[1]]

def get_max(hands): 
        hand_value = 0
        ace = False
        for card in hands:
            if card[0] == "A":
                ace =True;
            if card[:-1] in cards_value:  
                 hand_value += cards_value[card[:-1]]
            else:
                 hand_value += int(card[:-1])
        if ace and hand_value + 10 < 22:
                 hand_value += 10
        return hand_value
```

I'm just gonna add previous functions related to the topic for good measure:

```
deck = making_deck() # a function that shuffles 52 cards and makes deck.
def bjack_deal(deck, num_players): # num_players is a parameter manipulated by user

    hands = []
    for i in range(numplayers):

        hands.append([deck.pop(), deck.pop()])

    return hands
```

EDIT - Output should look something like this:

```
print (hands)
[['4D', 'KD'], ['QS', '9C'], ['TC', 'QC']] # This list is random, and the number of hands are determined by user

max_value = get_max(hands)

print(max_value)
20
```

Comment: Why are you summing up the two cards in the hand when you're trying to find the maximum? We _are_ trying to find the maximum and not the sum, right?

Comment: Hey Henry. If you need help, I suggest the first step is to create a [mcve]. At the very least, give us input and expected output. EDIT: Also, how are you counting Aces?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but this could help:

```
>>> cards_value = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10,'K':10}
>>> hands = [['4D', 'KD'], ['QS', '9C'], ['TC', 'QC']]
>>> sums = [sum(map(lambda x: cards_value[x[0]], hand)) for hand in hands]
>>> sums
[14, 19, 20]
>>> max(sums)
20
```